# SEVERE: Context [/AnilProject] startup failed due to previous errors whil deploying war on tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, logging

I am trying to deploy my war on tomcat1.7.
I have built that project with jdk1.6.
while deploying I am getting following exceptions...

```
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@1d648e2')
Nov 19, 2013 4:51:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter LogFilter## Heading ##    java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: /servlets/LoggingFilter : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class tcs.AnilProject.servlets.LoggingFilter)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2899)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:527)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:509)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4746)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5399)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1654)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Nov 19, 2013 4:51:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Nov 19, 2013 4:51:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Nov 19, 2013 4:51:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@a7bd7a')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem here is, I made my netbeans point to jdk1.6 but I am loading jdk1.7 jars.. So there is a mismatch of Java versions... So I couldn't deploy my war... Anyway, I am very happy that you all have spent some time to answer my question... Finally i could deploy the war after pointing to jdk1.6 jars while building...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe are you running Tomcat instance with different JRE/JDK? check your **JAVA_HOME** environment variable.